# Is it possible to set the height of a html table using css so that it grows wider instead of taller

Tags: html, css, width, tabular

Say I have a 4 row table with three cells in each row like this:

|000|000|000|
|000|000|000|
|000|000|000|
|000|000|000|

But I want to set the height to two rows so that it displays like this:

|000|000|000| |000|000|000|
|000|000|000| |000|000|000|

Is that possible?

Comment: do you have any code your worked on?

Comment: It’s really not possible, though in special cases it could be simulated. But why would you do that? If such a visual change makes sense, the odds are that you should not be using a table in the first place.

Comment: I don't think the `table`-tag is what you're looking for. Do you want the width of the corresponding columns to be the same?

Comment: I just have regular html mark-up for a table. I tried a couple of things but figured it wasn't possible but thought I'd ask. I can't change the html unfortunately.

Comment: yes I would like the corresponding columns to be the same but it wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible with table as far I know

This is a way to do it :
**CSS** :

```
.mytable {
 width: 200px;
 height:50px;
}
.row {
 float:left;
padding:5px;
}
.cell {
 float:left;
}

hr {
opacity:0;
clear:left;
}
```

Test this : http://jsfiddle.net/Y8Kej/

Comment: Cheers, though I do need to use a table unfortunately. I can't change the html.